# tmux on Windows (msys2) and non-admin fails

Tags: tmux, msys

Whe trying to run `tmux` as a non-admin I'm greeted with

```
failed to connect to server: Permission denied
```

It works fine when running msys-bash-mintty as administrator though.  Where should I start looking to solve this?  (Searching online hasn't produced anything useful yet.)

Versions:

- msys2 (just updated as I write this)
- tmux 2.0 (`tmux-git 1.9.4851.f8481f9-1`)

Comment: In the simple case, this means you started your first tmux session as another user, or as an administrator. Just attach as the same user and close every session; then start a new session as your normal user account, without admin.

Answer (score 0):

(I'd rather post this as a comment, but I can't comment yet.)

Try running "tmux -vvvv" to see what's the reason for the failure. You can also try running "strace tmux". Look for any errors right before the `failed to connect to server` message.

Note that the output is going to be very long. You may have to increase the scrollback buffer size in your MinTTY or redirect the output to a file.

Comment: I did find the issue, a folder lingering in `/tmp`.  Just running `rm -fr /tmp/tmux*` fixes the problem... of course it creates another; I can't detach and then re-attach sessions.  It's good enough to still be useful though.